# Attribute Table Missing Information

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, table

I'm taking a QGIS MOOC on Canvas, and in one of the labs we're to change layer style using an attribute table. However, the attribute table displays some very strange information on my system.  Attached is a picture... What's going on there?

Windows 7 Laptop - Acer
QGIS 2.6.1 Brighton

Attempts :

1. I have downloaded the data twice to replace it and started the lab from scratch.
2. I installed a package called "Table Manager" after reading SO, and restarted the software.
3. I changed the settings to "View all features."

At the very least, it appears I need the column headers to complete the lab assignment.

https://learn.canvas.net/courses/464/files/240563/download

You can download the data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B16xXw4nbuF0SHU1aTQ0UTlPUUU&authuser=0).

[image]

Comment: Looks like bad character encoding or possibly file corruption. Is it possible to link to the data source in question? Is there a place you can check if others in the course are or have had this problem? What format is the data - shapefile?

Comment: @ChrisW :: I've tried the course discussions with little response so far.  It is a dbf file.  [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B16xXw4nbuF0SHU1aTQ0UTlPUUU&authuser=0)

Comment: The link provided in your question doesn't appear to work, because it looks like it's restricted to having completed previous sections. The one in your comment does though. I opened it using Excel and everything looked fine (also Win7), so there might be a problem with fonts on your system. You could try opening it in another program to see if the issue is QGIS specific or system wide. Or it may be QGIS is incorrectly reading the encoding and you can follow AndreJ's answer to check/correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem loading the table as vector data using drag&drop, encoding is `System` (Windows 1252 latin 1). Headers are included, but no geometry information (i.e. coordinates).

You can rightclick on the layer, Properties -> General tab to see what encoding is used, and change the encoding.